# Exporting CellFrameLabels to HTML

Tags: export, html

I have a notebook that has several cells with CellFrameLabels and I'd like to export the notebook to HTML.  However, the CellFrameLabels are lost during export.

Here's an example of what I'm working with:

```
nb=CreateDocument[
 Cell["some text",
  CellFrameLabels->{{None,Cell["some related text"]},{None,None}},
  "cellstyle"]]
```

Then when I try

```
Export["testfile.html",nb,"HTML"]
```

all I get is

[image]

Ideally what I'd like is some way to pick out the value of the CellFrameLabels and then use ConversionRules to get something like

```
<div style="float:left">some text</div>   <div style="float:right">some related text</div>
```

If anyone can suggest a better way to achieve a similar result, I'm open to suggestions. That is, I don't *need* to use CellFrameLabels. So if there's another way to have two different alignments in a single cell in Mathematica, that will also export to HTML correctly then I'd be open to considering that.

Lastly, while I am fairly fluent in Mathematica, I have absolutely zero knowledge of HTML, so please be gentle.