# How to export to .html .nb file together with links «in» and «out»

Tags: export, html

If use «File > Save As > HTML» links «in» and «out» are lost

How to save a document without loss of these lines/links?

[image]
[image]

**UPD:** You can write in the css rules (`:after { content: "In[i]:="; }`) for `.Input` and `.Output`.

Example: http://wolframo.tk/nb/1s8efpc546a9986b3618.html

Application: https://github.com/latur/Wolframo

But it's not quite what I wanted

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13503/exporting-cellframelabels-to-htmlExporting CellFrameLabels to HTML related, I know many things will lost, for example CounterBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are `CellLabel`s and by default they are autodeleted when Notebook is saved. To preserve them, evaluate the following:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellLabelAutoDelete -> False]
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I need, thanks!